# How would I convert .obj/.mtl file to this proprietary Apple .model format?

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

The GLEssentials [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html) provides a 3D model in a file format called `.model`. (click "download sample code" at the top of the page and it's in `GLEssentials/GLEssentials/Data/Assets` folder)

As it turns out, this is a fairly popular **name** for a file extension but if you read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/GLEssentials/Listings/GLEssentials_Source_Utility_modelUtil_c.html) you'll see the comment:

> The model file
>     format used is a simple "binary blob" invented for the purpose of this sample code.

I'm not sure why they would invent a file format for the purposes of this test but I'm currently working with a tool that handles `.model` files well but I'm having issues with texturing `.obj` files (just a theory actually but I have to make a new `.model` file to test it).

You can find my issue discussing these problems in more detail [here](https://github.com/rastapasta/react-native-gl-model-view/issues/14) but the point of this question is to find out if there's any (reasonable) hope of creating a file of this format from an `.obj/.mtl` pair.

I'm going to try [this](https://github.com/edems96/.obj-to-.model-converter) tool that I found once my VM is done downloading but I don't have high hopes that we're talking about the same `.model` file type.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this github project](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GLView); it uses similar code to the Apple example you've linked, although it also supports `.obj` files. Keep in mind though that the code is deprecated and would need some changes to become compatible with the latest iOS.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm gonna look at that more closely later. It's a dependency for the project I linked here so it's very likely where the problem is: https://github.com/rastapasta/react-native-gl-model-view/issues/14